# Temporarily keeping image in memory before committing it to database in Django application

Tags: python, django, image

A Django `createview` class in my code sits behind a template, where a user can upload an image. This image is to be saved in `Picture` model, that has `image` and `caption` attributes respectively.

Once the user submits the image from the form, I need the image to *not yet be committed to the database*. Instead, the user is to first be shown **another template** where he can: (i) add a caption with the image (ii) or send it without a caption. Once the user submits this caption decision, **only then** do I want to commit the image to the database. Otherwise, I just want to remove it from memory.

How do I achieve this in `views.py`? Currently, I'm saving the image to the database in the first step (via creating a `Picture` object right away), and then just update this `Picture` object once the user decides about the caption later. This updating happens in another view class.

What options do I have to do it like I want it to happen? My backend is `postgresql`.

Comment: Can you not include the caption when you first select an image?

Comment: In this particular scenario, please assume that I can't. I'll do it if that's my only resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no great way to do this in Django. Objects in memory can't really be persisted from one request to another. It would almost certainly be better to try and re-structure your app's flow so that you don't have to do things this way.

However, If you *really, really* wanted to, one option would be to setup a [Local Memory Cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching), and temporarily persist the image there.

For example:

```
# In your settings
CACHES = {
    'images': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'images',
    }
}

# In your view, on the submit
from django.core.cache import caches
caches['images'].set('some-unique-cache-key', image_file.read(), 60)

'''Note: You'd probably want to set the cache key in the session,
so the other view can read it.'''

# In the other view, after the caption is set
from django.core.cache import caches
from django.core.files import File
import StringIO
tmp_file = StringIO.StringIO()
tmp_file.write(caches['images'].get('some-unique-cache-key'))

image_file = File(tmp_file)  # Now you have the image from the other view
```

You could also use a similar method with the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html) module to just save the file somewhere locally between the two views—this would probably be a little better on your app's memory usage, as well.